# Eclipse Mars 4.5.2:Cannot see dynamic web project

Tags: java, eclipse-mars

I have downloaded all these:
Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools
Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools
Eclipse Web Developer Tools
Eclipse XML Editors and Tools

Still not able to see Dynamic web project option.

[image]

Comment: You have 'hide items that are already installed' checked - the code is probably already installed. This dialog is for installing additional code. Note that Eclipse Neon is the current version of Eclipse.

Comment: i know i have hidden them. That means i have all installed items. Still it was not showing dynamic web project. My company does not allow me to download neon.

Answer (score 0):

search Dynamic Web Project in

> "type filter text"

Comment: It is not coming there.

Comment: did you installed IDE?